# Unity - Character doesn't stop moving even if not pressing anything

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Okay so here is the code:

```
// Variable to store character animator component
Animator animator;

// Variables to store optimized setter/getter parameter IDs
int isWalkingHash;
int isRunningHash;

// Variable to store the instance of the PlayerInput
PlayerInput input;

// Variables to store player input values
Vector2 currentMovement;
bool movementPressed;
bool runPressed;

// Awake is called when the script instance is being loaded
void Awake() 
{
     input = new PlayerInput();

    // Set the player input values using listeners
     input.CharacterControls.Movement.performed += ctx => {
        currentMovement = ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        movementPressed = currentMovement.x != 0 || currentMovement.y != 0;
     };  
     
     input.CharacterControls.Run.performed += ctx => runPressed = ctx.ReadValueAsButton();
}

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    // Set the animator reference
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();

    // Set ID references
    isWalkingHash = Animator.StringToHash("isWalking");
    isRunningHash = Animator.StringToHash("isRunning");
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    handleMovement();   
}

void handleMovement()
{
    // Get parameter values from animator
    bool isRunning = animator.GetBool(isRunningHash);
    bool isWalking = animator.GetBool(isWalkingHash);

    // Start walking if movement pressed is true and not already walking
    if (movementPressed && !isWalking) {
        animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, true);
    }

    // Stop walking if movementPressed is false and not already walking
    if (!movementPressed && isWalking) {
        animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, false);
    }

    // Start running if movement pressed and run pressed is true and not already running
    if ((movementPressed && runPressed) && isRunning) {
        animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, true);
    }

    // Stop running if movement pressed or run pressed is false and not currently running
    if ((!movementPressed || !runPressed) && isRunning) {
        animator.SetBool(isRunningHash, false);
    }
}

void OnEnable()
{
    //Enable the character control action map
    input.CharacterControls.Enable();
}

void OnDisable()
{
    //Disable the character control action map
    input.CharacterControls.Disable();
}
```

I am using `UnityEngine.InputSystem` at the start. But movement works fine, just when I let go WASD it is still moving in the last direction pressed. I really have no idea what is the problem here. I am just starting out so I don't know answers to the most simple questions. Sorry for bothering you. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `input.CharacterControls.Movement.performed` is also called with `0,0` if you are not pressing anything? Sounds to me like you are only getting the callback as long as the user actually presses at least one key but not if there is no key pressed at all => never reset the vector to 0,0.

Answer (score 0):

in the following block

```
// Stop walking if movementPressed is false and not already walking
    if (!movementPressed && isWalking) {
        animator.SetBool(isWalkingHash, false);
    }
```

you said you are checking 'not already walking'.
won't it be '!isWalking' as the if condition?

Comment: I don't think it's about the animator in the first place ... sounds to me like the movement itself is already wrong